# Drupal theme layout - recommendation based on example needed

Tags: theming

I am going to create a website that will have a layout similar (almost identical) to this one:
http://www.statoilfuelretail.com
Meaning:

- position of all the menus/elements
- picture in the background two
- columns in the middle

All the graphics will be made by graphic designer - **all I need is the theme (template) with layout I could use**. Would be great if it was a Drupal 7 theme.

My question is: **Which themes can you recommend (free and paid) that could be easily configured to match the layout presented on the website above?**

Comment: I think here is place for ask questions, it seams you put order here ;)

Comment: Hi REACHUS, welcome to Drupal Answers. You don't seem to have included a question in your post, which will make it impossible for people to answer you. Do you have a specific question that you would like the community to help you with? Please note that questions that will illicit discussion/opinion are not suitable for this site.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a specific question. It's not an order, I only ask for a recommendation. And yes, welcome everyone :)

Comment: @Reachus I think you may of misunderstood how the community operates. You will find Drupal help here, *but mabye not to choose your theme*. Consider [reading up on the awesome faq](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq) to get an idea of how the community operates, it is well worth the short read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I'd start with Bartik and go from there.  It's very solid and flexible.  It has the main elements you'll need.

But that's just me.  Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/corporateclean

If you are looking for something *extremely* quick and easy, your best bet is just browsing the different template websites that offer Drupal designs.  These have some themes similar to what you're looking for:

- http://www.templatemonster.com/drupal-themes.php
- http://www.themeshark.com/
- http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/
- http://www.sooperthemes.com/drupal-themes

Answer (score 0):

if you have HTNL/CSS Implemented version of your template. its very easy to convert it to Drupal theme. http://drupal.org/documentation/theme